# UnknownHostException while redirecting queries to google and getting results in JSon object

Tags: java, networking

```
Loading classifier from D:\PROJECT\classifiers\NERDemo\classifiers\ner-eng-ie.crf-3-all2008.ser.gz ... done [2.0 sec].
Original Query was riot in India.
Parsing Queries and expanding tokens from the Ontologies..
{locations=[India], events=[riot]}
Search query is null
Something went wrong...

java.net.UnknownHostException: ajax.googleapis.com
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at org.girs2.SearchHandler.makeQuery(SearchHandler.java:35)
 at org.girs2.GIRS.search(GIRS.java:37)
 at org.girs2.GIRS.main(GIRS.java:62)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.girs2.GIRS.search(GIRS.java:44)
 at org.girs2.GIRS.main(GIRS.java:62)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you probably have or had a DNS lookup failure.  This tells you what happened:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ajax.googleapis.com
```

If you always get this exception and you can otherwise access this host by name, then I don't know what this could be, but odds are that this was a temporary DNS failure.

What should you do when you get this Exception?  Well, if the address is one that you fully expect you should be able to get to -- such as this one -- then when you catch the Exception, you sleep for a while (perhaps 10 or 15 seconds, maybe even 30 or 60 seconds, depending on your application's needs) and try again.

If after several retries -- don't just retry forever! -- you still cannot reach the site, then log a reasonable complaint or otherwise complain that you cannot reach the site and have your application exit.

There's not much you can do when DNS fails except give up or wait and try again.